# excel VBA and statement with numbers

Tags: java, vba, excel

I'm re-writing an old vba app on excel to java, I found this lines:

```
a = b and (c-1)
```

b and c are numbers, so I tried doing and with numbers on the watch tab and I'm confused about the results

"5 and 3" equals 1

"3 and 4" equals 5

"123 And 55" equals 51

There's also a line with or:
2147455232 or &H80000000 equals -28416

this numbers are used to read a binary file that I need to load on java but can't make sense of those lines,

thanks in advance

Jose Suero

Comment: I think you mean "3 and 4" equals 0.

Answer (score 0):

These are using `And` and `Or` as bitwise operators:

```
1 and 1 = 1
1 and 0 = 0 and 1 = 0 and 0 = 0
```

For something like `123 And 55`: 123 = 1111011, 55 = 0110111 this is done component wise:

```
    1111011
and 0110111
    -------
    0110011    <= 51
```

`Or` is also being used bitwise: `0 or 0 = 0` and `0 or 1 = 1 or 0 = 1 or 1 = 1`

```
2147455232 or &H80000000 'a hex literal
```

in binary is:

```
   10000000000000000000000000000000
Or 01111111111111111001000100000000
   --------------------------------
 = 11111111111111111001000100000000
```

This last number is 4294938880, which wraps around to 4294938880 - 2^32 = -28416 when stored in a long.

Java also comes equipped with bit-wise operators (`&` for `And` and `|` for `Or`) -- although what happens with signed numbers can be a bit tricky, as your example with `Or` shows. Make sure that you use compatible data types (if the VBA codes uses 32-bit signed integers then the Java code should as well).